# Assert regex matches in JUnit

Tags: java, regex, junit

Ruby's `Test::Unit` has a nice `assert_matches` method that can be used in unit tests to assert that a regex matches a string.

Is there anything like this in JUnit? Currently, I do this:

```
assertEquals(true, actual.matches(expectedRegex));
```

Answer (score 116, accepted):

If you use `assertThat()` with a [Hamcrest matcher](http://piotrga.wordpress.com/2009/03/27/hamcrest-regex-matcher/) that tests for regex matches, then if the assertion fails you'll get a nice message that indicates expected pattern and actual text. The assertion will read more fluently also, e.g.

```
assertThat("FooBarBaz", matchesPattern("^Foo"));
```

with Hamcrest 2 you can find a `matchesPattern` method at `MatchesPattern.matchesPattern`.

#### JUnit5:

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
assertThat(actual).matches(expected);
```

Comment: Hamcrest 2.0 has the `Matchers.matchesPattern(String)` now built-in: https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/blob/master/hamcrest-library/src/main/java/org/hamcrest/Matchers.java#L1401

Comment: Permalink for what @hinneLinks refers to: https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/blob/8f9372a152612b45f51a12d1c549643fdac5492a/hamcrest-library/src/main/java/org/hamcrest/Matchers.java#L1474-L1480

Answer (score 60):

No other choice that I know. Just checked the [`assert` javadoc](http://www.junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/Assert.html) to be sure.
Just a tiny little change, though:

```java
assertTrue(actual.matches(expectedRegex));
```

EDIT: I have been using the Hamcrest matchers since pholser's answer, check that out too!

Comment: Ah yes, `assertTrue()` is definitely nicer. I blame Eclipse's auto-complete for me not knowing about that. ;)

Comment: `assertTrue` can't give you as much detail as `assertEquals` or `assertThat` when a test fails

Comment: @Michael Sure it can. `assertTrue("Expected string matching '" +expectedRegex+ "'. Got: "+actual, actual.matches(expectedRegex));`. It's not as nice as Hamcrest though.

Comment: @MikeValenty If you're just comparing a value to `is(true)`, then `assertThat` doesn't give you any more detail than `assertTrue` does. To get proper error messages, you need a different matcher (or you construct the message manually as @MikeFHay suggested).

Comment: Important: string.matches() is available from version 8 of java and in that version it doesn't support multiline, even using the respective flag (?m); then you'd need to do it in the old verbose way: Pattern.compile() then matcher.find()

Answer (score 22):

You can use Hamcrest, but you have to write your own matcher:

```
public class RegexMatcher extends TypeSafeMatcher<String> {

    private final String regex;

    public RegexMatcher(final String regex) {
        this.regex = regex;
    }

    @Override
    public void describeTo(final Description description) {
        description.appendText("matches regex=`" + regex + "`");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matchesSafely(final String string) {
        return string.matches(regex);
    }


    public static RegexMatcher matchesRegex(final String regex) {
        return new RegexMatcher(regex);
    }
}
```

usage

```
import org.junit.Assert;


Assert.assertThat("test", RegexMatcher.matchesRegex(".*est");
```

Answer (score 18):

You can use Hamcrest and [jcabi-matchers](http://matchers.jcabi.com):

```
import static com.jcabi.matchers.RegexMatchers.matchesPattern;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
assertThat("test", matchesPattern("[a-z]+"));
```

More details here: [Regular Expression Hamcrest Matchers](http://matchers.jcabi.com/regex-matchers.html).

You will need these two dependencies in classpath:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
  <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.3</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.jcabi</groupId>
  <artifactId>jcabi-matchers</artifactId>
  <version>1.3</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I have found that the hamcrest-core dependency is not needed

Answer (score 4):

Because I was also looking for this functionality, I have started a project on GitHub called [regex-tester](https://github.com/nickawatts/regex-tester). It's a library that helps ease testing regular expressions in Java (only works with JUnit currently).

The library is very limited right now, but it does have a Hamcrest matcher that works like this

```
assertThat("test", doesMatchRegex("tes.+"));
assertThat("test", doesNotMatchRegex("tex.+"));
```

More about how to use regex-tester is [here](http://thewonggei.com/2014/02/08/introducing-the-regex-tester-library-for-java/).

Answer (score 4):

A matcher similar to Ralph's implementation has been [added](https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/issues/36) to the official Java Hamcrest matchers library. Unfortunately, it's not yet available in a release package. The class is on [GitHub](https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/blob/master/hamcrest-library/src/main/java/org/hamcrest/text/MatchesPattern.java) though if you want a look.

Answer (score 4):

another alternative using assertj.  this approach is nice as it allows you to pass the pattern object directly.

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
assertThat("my\nmultiline\nstring").matches(Pattern.compile("(?s)my.*string", Pattern.MULTILINE));
```

Answer (score 4):

**An update for JUnit 5, without any extra library.**

Now you can use `assertLinesMatch` as described in https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.1/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertLinesMatch-java.util.List-java.util.List-

The assertion was created to match several lines of text, so you need to provide a `List` even if you try to match only one line. For e.g.:

```
assertLinesMatch(List.of("Expected at the beginning.*"), List.of(contentUnderTest));
```

The assertion algorithm will try an exact match and then, if it fails, will use `String.match` interpreting the expected value as a regular expression.

***An important note:*** if your `contentUnderTest` contains several lines, then the `.*` in the regex won't work (`.` doesn't match a new line character by default) so you may need to add an embedded flag (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL):

```
// Flag ?s means match new lines
assertLinesMatch(List.of("(?s)Expected at the beginning.*"), List.of(contentWithMultipleLines));
```

Answer (score 3):

There is corresponding matcher in Hamcrest: [org.hamcrest.Matchers.matchesPattern(String regex)](https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/blob/master/hamcrest-library/src/main/java/org/hamcrest/Matchers.java#L1478).

[As development of Hamcrest stalled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33776809/hamcrest-what-version-to-use-1-3-or-2) you can't use latest available v1.3:

```
testCompile("org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3")
```

Instead you need to use new dev series (but still [dated by Jan 2015](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/java-hamcrest)):

```
testCompile("org.hamcrest:java-hamcrest:2.0.0.0")
```

or even better:

```
configurations {
    testCompile.exclude group: "org.hamcrest", module: "hamcrest-core"
    testCompile.exclude group: "org.hamcrest", module: "hamcrest-library"
}
dependencies {
    testCompile("org.hamcrest:hamcrest-junit:2.0.0.0")
}
```

In test:

```
Assert.assertThat("123456", Matchers.matchesPattern("^[0-9]+$"));
```

Comment: I get error: Duplicate class org.hamcrest.BaseDescription found in modules jetified-hamcrest-core-1.3.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3) and jetified-java-hamcrest-2.0.0.0.jar (org.hamcrest:java-hamcrest:2.0.0.0)

Answer (score 2):

it's not JUnit but here is another way with fest-assert :

```
assertThat(myTestedValue).as("your value is so so bad").matches(expectedRegex);
```