# Hamcrest - what version to use? 1.3 or 2

Tags: java, junit, hamcrest

I am quite confused. Currently I am testing my spring application using

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I was happy as long as I wanted to match RegularExpressions. In hamcrest 1.3 you need to write your own matcher, which I did not like that much.
I searched and found that hamcrest 2.0 has something build in, like:

```
assertThat(DateHelper.getActualDateForXML(), MatchesPattern.matchesPattern("\\d{4}+-\\d{2}-+\\d{2}+T\\d{2}+:\\d{2}+:\\d{2}+"));
```

I was happy, I added:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
    <artifactId>hamcrest-junit</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

And kicked out the 1.3 hamcrest dependencies from spring-boot-starter-test:

```
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
       <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
       <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
       <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
       <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

Now everything is still working as I expect it to work, but I do not feel really comfortable. Because I can just find people writing about 1.3 and can not really find the use of hamcrest-junit 2.0.

Can somebody explain me the connection between them? Because it seems that hamcrest-junit 2.0 has everything build in from hamcrest 1.3...

Thanks Ben

Comment: You can't find documentation on the difference between 2.0 and 1.3 because the project [has not been properly maintained for quite a few months][1].  If an active committer takes over, then we will all know.  Thanks @CoronA.

Comment: Related: [Snippet on how to setup Junit with hamcrest propertly](http://acdcjunior.github.io/java-unit-tests-maven-dependencies-junit-hamcrest-mockito.html)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

EDIT: After several years ***the answer is to use the latest Hamcrest 2 version*** ([2.2 from 17th October 2019](https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/blob/master/CHANGES.md)). For additional details also refer to [@dschulten's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54060569/5698098).

Following is my original answer which I leave as context to understand the problem and confusion around Hamcrest versions 1.3 and 2.0.0.0 back in the day.

---

Based on Hamcrest Github

- [Hamcrest Github CHANGES.md](https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/blob/master/CHANGES.md)
- [Decouple the evolution of Hamcrest and JUnit](https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/issues/92)
- [Is this still being maintained?](https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/issues/131)

and [JUnit Lambda (Junit 5)](http://junit.org/junit-lambda.html)

- [Minimize dependencies (especially third-party)](https://github.com/junit-team/junit-lambda/wiki/Core-Principles#minimize-dependencies-especially-third-party)

***My take on it***

- hamcrest-junit 2.0 (should be) is a fresh start with also the goal to decouple hamcrest from junit
- in the meantime Junit 5 project kicked off which reduces/removes third party dependencies

=> In this situation, I expect it is prudent for the hamcrest guys to wait for / coordinate with the JUnit 5 project before moving forward substantially.

As @heenenee mentioned, the hamcrest guys became busy with other stuff and so not much is happening with the project at this point.

***To answer***

> Can somebody explain me the connection between them? Because it seems that hamcrest-junit 2.0 has everything build in from hamcrest 1.3

- hamcrest-junit 2.0 started but the guys behind it got busy soon after (and still are) with other projects, so the development stopped
- there might also be some uncertainties regarding JUnit 5 which may be an incentive to defer further hamcrest-junit 2.0 development until the JUnit 5 release (speculation)

> ... but I do not feel really comfortable. Because I can just find people writing about 1.3 and can not really find the use of hamcrest-junit 2.0.

At the moment, other than for your case there is not much incentive to move to hamcrest-junit 2.0. Once Junit 5 releases I expect that there will be more incentive to move forward again.

Comment: JUnit 5 is here and they decoupled testing framework from assertion framework. Since that time up to 2018 there haven't been releases of Hamcrest. On other hands `AspectJ` is sound alternative.

Comment: @gavenkoa `AspectJ` comes with various strings attached, so it's not a viable alternative for every project.

Comment: Changelog of hamcrest is now at https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/blob/master/CHANGES.md

Answer (score 12):

The Hamcrest project has just [released 2.1](https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/blob/master/CHANGES.md), and they [reworked the package structure](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/distributables) after [thorough consideration](https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/issues/224). Make sure you follow the [upgrade procedure](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/distributables#upgrading-from-hamcrest-1x).
The artifact java-hamcrest 2.0.0.0 is considered a [failed attempt](https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/issues/224#issuecomment-438811026) now.

Comment: Almost didnt see this answer due to the low vote count. thx for update

Answer (score 3):

Great answer by [Ivo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5698098/ivo-mori), which really should be getting more votes, but here's some added information. If you check Maven for information on the dependencies, [Java Hamcrest 2.0.0.0](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/java-hamcrest/2.0.0.0) and [Hamcrest JUnit 2.0.0.0](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-junit/2.0.0.0), there are some [usage](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/java-hamcrest/usages) links. At the time I write this, it's 74 and 68 respectively, and no major projects from a brief browsing.

Comment: this has changed quite a bit, it now stands at 500 usages, among them some major projects...