# how to match header location response with regular expression using rest-assured

Tags: java, regex, rest, hamcrest, rest-assured

I was making a rest-assured test for testing url redirects using testng. I would like to match header location response to match with regular expression.

I am trying to create following method but I didn't find any regular expression matcher using Hamcrest matcher. I would like to use some method like matches (or if any other option) as used in the method.

```
public Response matchRedirect(String url, Integer statusCode, String urlRegex) {
        return  
        given().
                redirects().follow(false).and().redirects().max(0).
         expect(). 
                 statusCode(statusCode). 
                 header("Location", **matches**(urlRegex)). 
         when().get(url); 
}
```

Comment: Try `matchesPattern(urlRegex)`. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8509102/3832970). And perhaps, [this link](http://matchers.jcabi.com/regex-matchers.html) will be of help.

Answer (score 2):

I used class from https://piotrga.wordpress.com/2009/03/27/hamcrest-regex-matcher/ to use with my method.

```
import org.hamcrest.BaseMatcher;
import org.hamcrest.Description;

public class RegexMatcher extends BaseMatcher<Object>{
  private final String regex;

  public RegexMatcher(String regex){
      this.regex = regex;
  }

  public boolean matches(Object o){
      return ((String)o).matches(regex);

  }

  public void describeTo(Description description){
      description.appendText("matches regex=");
  }

  public static RegexMatcher matches(String regex){
      return new RegexMatcher(regex);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom matcher:

```
import org.hamcrest.BaseMatcher;
import org.hamcrest.Description;
import org.hamcrest.Matcher;

public class CustomMatchers {

    public static Matcher<String> matchesRegex(final String regex) {
        return new BaseMatcher<String>() {

            public boolean matches(final Object item) {
                return ((String) item).matches(regex);
            }

            public void describeTo(final Description description) {
                description.appendText("should match regex: " + regex);
            }
        };
    }

}
```

And then check that the header match your regex:

```
public Response matchRedirect(String url, Integer statusCode, String urlRegex) {
        return  
        given().
                redirects().follow(false).and().redirects().max(0).
        expect(). 
                statusCode(statusCode). 
                header("Location", CustomMatchers.matchesRegex(urlRegex)). 
        when().get(url); 
}
```